# What is a proper syntax style for function strings in php

Tags: php, syntax, standards

I'm learning php, and i notice its an extreme rich language with string related functions.
Something i've not seen in other languages is the code below, i know its basics.
But what i wonder what is the common syntax style, to use for this.

I just used f_...... to declare a function that is already usable.

And i used sf_...... to put a function into its string callable form.

I also tend to use a_ for arrays etc.
But i am wondered is there some kind of popular standard.
With popular i mean used often but doesnt need to be compliant to specific complex norms. i would just like to achive that other coders find it easy to read.

```
    function f_RedText($a){ return "<font size='+1' color='#ff0000'>$a</font>";}
    $sf_redtext = "f_RedText";
    echo $sf_redtext("Peter");
```

Comment: Hungarian notation [isn't a good idea](https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html). Just make the name descriptive.

Comment: I'd guess that the most common standard is camel case rather than Hungarian notation

Comment: Hungarian notation is sooooo last millennium… and was a bad idea even back then.

Comment: php cant even agree on naming standards eg substr and str_replace. Just make the name descriptive and stay to a single standard. http://www.php-fig.org is a nice standard to follow in general

Comment: Suggesting to look at the [Zend code style guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html) especially the part about "Methods and Functions".

Comment: I don't use hungarian but do use camelcase for classes, functions, and methods and lower case with underscores for variables and properties. UPPERCASE for static or constants, etc.

Comment: OK i'm interested in the line sf_.....  or sf....  (without underscore) i thought since a lot internal php functions use an underscore it would be clear that those are 'local' names. but thats just me, i rather folow whats the best for sf...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exactly fit your question but is a more general approach to coding guidelines in PHP.

Have a look at [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md)

**Edit**

or [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html) or [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) or [Nette](http://doc.nette.org/en/2.1/coding-standard) (hat tip to @DanFromGermany for comment ;))

Comment: [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) | [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html) | [FIG PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) | [Nette](http://doc.nette.org/en/2.1/coding-standard) :-)

Answer (score -4):

You can use what you think, keeping mind the php documentation. If you wrote `function f_RedText($a)` then its ok. Developers use as they want to use. There is nothing standard pattern that all good developers have to follow.

Comment: Downvote because: A good developer always follows standards (Zend, PSR, PEAR).

Comment: Although there is no standard pattern, there are best practices (notice the "s") and not-so-good practices. I would say it's a good idea to ask, especially when learning a language, so that you get good habits, and there are definitely some good advises out there for coding standards... Advising doing "whatever you want" to someone trying to go into a good direction is a bad advice if you ask me... => downvote